# Why jQuery results look like a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

If I create a jQuery wrapped set and put it into `console.log`, it will look like

[image]

---

I know that we can "trick" the `console` in displaying `objects` or `arrays`, that means if we have

```
var obj = {
    0: 'some',
    1: 'data'
};
```

it will output as

[image]

But if we add a `splice method` and `length property`, it will become

[image]

---

**Question**: How can I create a function, that creates such an `array-like object`, but still shows in the console as a `function` like `jQuery` does ? I don't understand the jQuery code for that.

**result like**:  `myFunction( "some", "data" )`

---

Update:

It seems like I didn't make myself clear enough. I want to know, how I can create and setup a function, a constructor, whatever to have an `array-like object` which prints in the console as a `function( elem1, elem2, ...)`. A perfect answer contains a quick example for that.

Comment: Does it really matter how it looks in the console as long as you can read it, and why would it matter, and what are you using this for (just really curious)? +1 for the effort on the question btw.

Comment: I took the screenshots with the latest firefox + firebug. I only want to know how I can accomplish this output.

Comment: I'd guess it just logs `obj.constructor.name` if available. Which jQuery do you use, development version?

Comment: How did you get that `jQuery(div#notify...` output? What did you do to display that?

Comment: I guess that this behaviour is due to the addon `FireQuery`. But I don't knwo how they obtain this logging...

Comment: You can obtains this logging with `FireQuery`. If you have FireQuery, just do `console.log($('*'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default appearance of a jQuery object in the firebug console is `Object[one, two, ...]`.
You can have the same thing if you use an `array-like object` with a constructor. As in the Chad response.

But in your case, you got a "special appearance" for jQuery objects because of a Firefox plugin called FireQuery : http://firequery.binaryage.com/

As far as i know, you can't have the same result in the firebug console. Except if you make your own plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Have you used [console.dir()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.dir)

```
>>> var myA = ["a","b","c"];  console.dir(myA);
  0    "a"
  1    "b"
  2    "c"
```

Comment: I used `console.log` for all three outputs indeed, not `console.dir()`. How to achieve the jQuery look ?

Answer (score 0):

It just outputs the value of `Object.constructor.name` if it exists:

```
>>> var Mine = function() {}
undefined

>>> new Mine()
Object {}

//-------------------------------

>>> function Mine() {}
undefined

>>> new Mine()
Mine {}

//-------------------------------

>>> function Mine() {}
undefined

>>> Mine.prototype.length = 10;
10

>>> Mine.prototype.splice = function() {}
function()

>>> new Mine()
Object[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

Which matches the output I get for jQuery in my console:

```
>>> jQuery('span');
Object[span.profile-triangle, span.reputation-score, span, span.badge2, ...]
```

I am using Firefox v17.0.1, and Firebug v1.11.1

Hope this helps.

**Edit:** Also note that `Function.name` is read-only once the function is created<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)</sup>